# How to use functions for 3 OR conditions expressions

Tags: function, expression

I currently have this: =or(a, b)

But need to add c. How do I create an expression that if it equals a, b or c.
Thanks

Comment: What is the context? Google Sheets, a programming langauge, etc?

Comment: Thanks Doug,  its C#. I currently have it like this =or(=//Job/XX, =/Job/XX) and it works fine. I need to add another one, but its saying  the OR function should only have {expr1, expr2}.

Comment: I've figured it out now, Thanks. =OR(a, OR=(a, b))

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out now, Thanks. =OR(a, OR=(a, b))